# How to deal with "" within strings in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am currently creating a function in haskell like:

```
allStrings :: [String] -> String
```

What i want the function to do is take a list of strings and then split each string with a space character

`so say input = ["Today", "Tomorrow"] output = "Today Tomorrow"`

One problem i am running into is how to deal with strings that contain `""` and char to represent new lines i am not sure how to deal with those i know that quote marks within strings are surrounding by `\` what i want to do when we come across quote marks in our string is like so:

`input ["Sun\"shine\" ", "Rain"] becomes output -> "Sun""shine" Rain"`

is anyone able to help me with how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: are you allowed to use built-in functions or do you need to implement everything from scratch with explicit recursion?

Comment: @user1984 i could use built in functions like intercalate for the splitting with a space but yeah if you have an answer using built in functions or from scratch using explicit recursion go for it any answer is appreciated

Comment: Where is your code that works without dealing with escaped quotes? I recommend solving the simpler problem, then trying to handle escaped `"`s inside the strings. Without any code shown, this evaluates to "do it for me", which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The best method I'm aware of that joins `String`s together in Haskell with a single whitespace is [`unwords`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unwords).
Having the following signature:

```hs
λ> :t unwords
unwords :: [String] -> String
```

it perfectly suits your needs.

As for how a string containing a `"` is displayed (for example the output from `unwords`, if it contains a `"` will have a `\"`, that's a printing issue.

If you want the `\`s to disappear while displaying the string, use [`putStrLn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) with the following signature:

```hs
λ> :t putStrLn
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Like so:

```hs
λ> putStrLn $ unwords ["Sun\"shine\" ", "Rain"]
Sun"shine"  Rain
```

Comment: how can u get rid of the \ without the use or putStrLn as that is of type IO when i wanted type string